# Gridview -- DataSource: empty vs nothing

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am working on a legacy application, and when the datatable that would be bound to the DataSource is empty (i.e. has no rows), the DataSource is instead bound to Nothing.

I would expect this to give a neligible performance increase at best, and I can't think of any other reason to do this.

Is there something I'm missing?  Is there either a behaviorial or significant performance difference beween a datasource that has no rows versus a datasource that is null?

UPDATE: The columns are being defined in the aspx, not autogenerated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how you are specifying the column definitions (ie: either having them being generated on the fly or before hand) you may have a visual difference in the grid layout (A grid with source of nothing will obviously not auto-generate the the columns).  However strictly speaking from a memory management and performance perspective I would think that the null dataset/datatable would be have a lower footprint because you would not cause the grid to fire its dataset initialization events.

In the grand scheme of things, I don't think you'd actually see much of a measurable time / memory difference either way unless your routine to create the empty dataset/datatable takes a significant amount of time.

I'd love to hear other folks opinions on the topic.

Comment: I just checked, and the DataBinding and DataBound events are fired either way.  I should have mentioned the columns, I had considered them, but they aren't being autogenerated.

Comment: Is it possible that binding a null data source causes the grid to release some of its internal allocation structures which may have been allocated previously when the grid was bound to an actual non null object.